# What is the character returned from "\n\n" when exploded with respect to "\n" using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I have added some data in a DB. The text contains both English and Arabic. So, while I need to display the text in webpage, I am trying to split the total text into paragraphs.

1. Then if a paragraph contains `Arabic` text, I am displaying the text
   in a div with "*right-to-left*" alignment.
2. If the text is in `English`, it is displayed in "*left-to-right*" alignment.

So here's is my following code:

```
/*------ Allign text ------*/
function align_text($text)
{
    $string = $text;
    $returnString = '';
    $paraArray = explode("\n", $string);
    if(count($paraArray) > 0)
    {
        foreach($paraArray as $pa)
        {
            $isRight = $this->is_rtl($pa);
            if($isRight)
            {
                $para['para'] = $pa;
                $para['align'] = 'R';
            }
            else
            {
                $para['para'] = $pa;
                $para['align'] = 'L';
            }
            $paraArr[] = $para;
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
    return $paraArr;
}

function is_rtl($string) 
{
    $rtl_chars_pattern = '/[\x{0590}-\x{05ff}\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]/u';
    return preg_match($rtl_chars_pattern, $string);
}
```

Now, here is the problem.

```
Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( 
                          [para] => This is testing mail. 
                          [align] => L ) 
          [1] => Array ( 
                          [para] => This is testing mail. This is testing mail. This is testing mail. 
                          [align] => L ) 
          [2] => Array ( 
                          [para] => 
                          [align] => L ) 
          [3] => Array ( 
                          [para] => This is testing mail. 
                          [align] => L ) );
```

As you can see, the 2nd row(if counted from 0th row) has `{ [para] => }`.
That is because of "\n\n" i.e. two consecutive newlines or `<enter>`.

**What is the character that I am getting here?**

When trying to display the result like this,

```
<?php
    if(!is_array($row['chatDesc']))
    {?>
        <div class="com-text">
            <?php echo $row['chatDesc'];?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($row['chatDesc'] as $rC)
        { 
            echo strlen($rC['para']);
            if(strlen($rC['para'])==1 && 
                ($rC['para']==null || $rC['para']=="" || $rC['para']==" " || $rC['para']=="\n"))
            {?>
                <div class="com-text" style="direction:rtl; clear:both">
                [AAA<?php echo $rC['para'];?>AAA]
                </div>
        <?php 
            }
            else if($rC['align']=='R' && $rC['para']!=' ')
            {?>
                <div class="com-text" style="direction:rtl; clear:both">
                    [<?php echo $rC['para'];?>]
                </div>
        <?php 
            }
            else if($rC['align']=='L' && $rC['para']!=' ')
            {?>
                <div class="com-text" style="direction:ltr;clear:both">
                    [<?php echo $rC['para'];?>]
                </div>
    <?php   }
        }
    }   ?>
```

I am unable to determine the `{ [para] => }`.
I am never getting this div displayed:-

```
<div class="com-text" style="direction:rtl; clear:both">
[AAA<?php echo $rC['para'];?>AAA]
</div>
```

But if I change the condition,

```
if(strlen($rC['para'])==1 && 
                    ($rC['para']==null || $rC['para']=="" || $rC['para']==" " || $rC['para']=="\n"))
```

to only `if(strlen($rC['para'])==1)`, the div is getting displayed.

The content of the div is `[AAA AAA]`. There is an extra space between the pairs of AAA. If this character is indeed a `<space>` then why the initial condition in the `if statement` isn't satisfying?

Comment: Try to use `chr()` function to define symbol http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: Start by using var_dump() instead of print_r() to see more details about the type, length and contents of the variable. In other words ````var_dump($rC)```` should provide you with what you need. Depending on your source data the "invisible" character might be ````\r```` or other type of whitespace character.

Comment: Could be `\r` or space.

Comment: @kb. I am getting  `{ 'para' => string(1) " "` as stated by var_dump.

Comment: @Saswat I just tried your `if statement` and it works fine for me ._.

Comment: @kb. You were right. It's `\r`. But isn't it the same as ` `?

Comment: @Saswat No it's a separate character, however you could do a ````$para['para'] = trim($pa);```` in your align_text() function to get rid of several kinds of whitespace characters including ````\r````. *(It's often recommended to do when splitting text on ````\n```` since it's possible that the text actually uses ````\r\n```` and this also makes "empty" lines that consist of only a space to become empty strings for real.)*

Comment: Saswat, how did you get on with the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the if statement you've provided with the `\n\n`, however, it worked fine for me. As a solution that will fix all the white space characters, I've done some refactoring of your function to remove any unnecessary white spaces from your paragraph and only push it to the array if the paragraph is not empty.

```
function align_text($text){
    $result = array();

    foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $paragraph){
        // Remove any whitespace from the beginning and end of the paragraph
        $paragraph = trim($paragraph);

        // Only append the paragraph if it's not empty
        if(strlen($paragraph) > 0)
            array_push($result, array('para' => $paragraph, 'align' => is_rtl($paragraph) ? 'R' : 'L'));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And you don't need that many if cases to display your divs in your HTML:

```
<?php foreach($row['chatDesc'] as $rC): ?>
    <div class="com-text" style="direction:<?php echo $rC['align'] == 'L' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl' ?>;clear:both;">
        <?php echo $rC['para']; ?>  
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, if you only use the `align` for the div alignment, you could also set it to `ltr` or `rtl` directly in your align_text function.

```
array_push($result, array('para' => $paragraph, 'align' => is_rtl($paragraph) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'));
```

Then in your html, you could simply echo the align:

```
<?php foreach($row['chatDesc'] as $rC): ?>
<div class="com-text" style="direction:<?php echo $rC['align'] ?>;clear:both;">
```